# Slow drawInRect with same image

Tags: ios, performance, uiview, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a custom view inheriting from `UIView`.

In this view, there is an image which is always the same and I only want to draw on top of that.

However, in order for the image to be drawn, I have to call `drawInRect` every time the draw cycle runs.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawInRect:self.bounds];
    // drawing....
}
```

Is there a way to show the image and not to call this method every time `drawRect` is invoked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image in a `UIImageView` underneath your custom `UIView` instead of drawing it in `drawRect:`.  Make your custom view's background color `clearColor` so the image shows through where `drawRect:` doesn't draw anything.

Don't try to make the image view a subview of your custom view.  A subview always draws on top of its superview's content.  You could make your custom view a subview of the image view, or you could make them siblings.

Comment: That's quite clever Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In the .h file of the custom class do this:

```
- (void)  setup:
```

Then in the .m do this:

```
-(void) setup {
    //drawing stuff
}
```

Then in the view did load of whatever the view controller that adds it as a subview is

```
[myCustomView setup];
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not work, since it is irrelevant every time drawRect: is called

Comment: This method would work if implemented correctly but another solution if you wish to use draw react would be to create a bool in that class, like bool didDrawOnce. You can put that in the .h or .m.  Then in draw rect: if (didDrawOnce == no) { do drawing and then didDrawOnce = yes;}. That way you only draw the first time you hit draw rect.

Comment: But I want the drawing to be persistent. If I only call it once, it won't draw the image the next time I call drawRect

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, why don't you tell me the exact context of what you are trying to do by doing this so i can offer a solution to fit it.